# Is there a better way to write this functino which periodically check for DOM element?

Tags: javascript

I need to know when the element with ID has been loaded.  I check for it every 10ms.

```
function pageLoaded (id, callback) {
    var isLoaded = document.getElementById(id);
    var id_interval = setInterval( function() {
        if (isLoaded) {
            callback();
            clearInterval(id_interval)
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: A better way is not to write this function at all, but wait for the respective event. How is the element "loaded"?

Comment: What do you mean loaded? When the ID first comes in, or when it is manipulated with something like .text() or .html()?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how the content is loaded?

Comment: It is a simple div that is loaded in index.html with the id = id.

Comment: As mentioned events would be the far better solution. However (because I think its a cracking API) mutation observers would allow to know when an element has been added to a parent and more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Well, if you control the interjection point then why not just trigger an event from there? Because to set a interval to run a  check every 10ms is not exactly the best way to check if an element is there.

Comment: for whatever reason JS can not detect a div loaded below it in the HTML page.

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });